# How to add Maven to the Path variable windows 10?

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

Then I tried to add it to the path of Windows 10 as below:

Right click on my computer

Properties

Advanced System Setting

Environment Variable

New user variable and added Maven_Home with value:

`C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Selenium Course\apache-maven-3.8.1\bin`

Add it to path variable with:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;`

Open cmd and ask for mvn -version in desktop

CMD : `'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Any help please

Comment: try in a new command prompt window after saving path

Comment: First remove `MAVEN_HOME` because it's not needed. Just use the path `C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Selenium Course\apache-maven-3.8.1\bin` in your `PATH` variable. Or if you like to keep `MAVEN_HOME` then remove `\bin` from `PATH` variable otherwise you have `..\apache-maven-3.8.1\bin\bin` which is the reason for not working.

Answer (score 1):

Inside System variables add:

- Variable name: MAVEN_HOME
- Variable value: \apache-maven-3.8.4

Then on your path add:

- %MAVEN_HOME%\bin

Don't forget to restart your terminal. Then check if it's working with the command `mvn -version`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `bin` from MAVEN_HOME. When the path is building you add `bin` again, then the path the machine is looking for is

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin\bin;
```

which is wrong.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't notice, but your answer already appears in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68085723/how-to-add-maven-to-the-path-variable-windows-10#comment120338767_68085723).